# How do you export the result of a RevolutionPlot3D to STL for printing?

Tags: plotting, export, 3d-printing

How do you export the result of a RevolutionPlot3D to [STL (STereoLithography) file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_%28file_format%29) for printing? I am a tyro when it comes to 3D rendering and printing.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Comment: Related: [Creating a 3D mesh plot and exporting it to an STL file for 3D printing](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/139463). I mention this MSE post in my reply there too.

Answer (score 17):

### Update

Please see Printout3D and related guides:

- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/MakeA3DPrintout.html
- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Printout3D.html
- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/3DPrinting.html

### Older

This is very easy. Design a model, for example:

```
model = RevolutionPlot3D[{Sin[t] + Sin[5 t]/10, 
   Cos[t] + Cos[5 t]/10}, {t, 0, Pi}, 
  RegionFunction -> (Sin[5 (#4 + #5)] > 0 &), Mesh -> None, 
  BoundaryStyle -> Black, PlotStyle -> Thickness[.1]]
```

[image]

Note a special setting `PlotStyle -> Thickness[.1]` which gives thickness to the model walls - yo can set your own value of course. Now export to STL and then re-import to verify file was created and see how it looks

```
Export["model.stl", model];
Import[%]
```

[image]

The STL file can be just sent to 3D printer. The best part? - Wolfram has a whole course on 3D printing - tips how to make it work nicely:

[Scan, Convert, and Print: Playing with 3D Objects in Mathematica Q&A](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?channel=317&video=1453)

with the [**notebook**](http://www.wolfram.com/training/special-event/wolfram-visualization-virtual-workshop-2013/PlayingWith3DObjectsInMathematica.zip). You may also want to take a look at

- [Makerbot Constructions - George W. Hart](http://www.georgehart.com/rp/makerbot/makerbot.html)
- [Notes on 3D printing](http://www.segerman.org/3d_printing_notes.html)
- [Henry Segerman's Mathematical Art](http://www.shapeways.com/shops/henryseg)

Comment: Good one, Vitaliy! Notice that STL files don't have dimensions or units, so at one point in the submission process for many 3D printer services you have to specify what that -1.0 to 1.0 size signifies - meters, inches, or millimeters, for example. If you know in advance what you can specify, you can scale the graphic suitably.