# Exporting a spherical gyroid for 3D printing

Tags: export, 3d-printing

I have been able to wite a code which can produce a 3D contour plot if a spherical gyroid. Now I need to add a thickness to the gyroid. I also want to know how to export the 3D drawing to other software like Netfabb or Inventer so that I can do a 3D printing of the object I obtained.

[image]

This was the code I was given by one of the experts here.

```
r = 10 Pi;
ContourPlot3D[
  Sin[x] Cos[y] + Sin[y] Cos[z] + Sin[z] Cos[x] == 0, 
  {x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}, {z, -r, r},
  RegionFunction -> ({x, y, z} \[Function] x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= r^2), 
  Mesh -> None]
```

I really need to do a 3D printing of this. I in urgent need of assistance. Please help me.

Comment: Relevant https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27728/how-do-you-export-the-result-of-a-revolutionplot3d-to-stl-for-printing

Answer (score 4):

I did print a spherically cropped gyroid generated with Mathematica. I remember it was a lot of fuss to generate a usable file. Unfortunately, I did not make notes, as *as I remember* it was this one I used in the end (copied from an old notebook):

```
a = 3 \[Pi];
mesh = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
    ImplicitRegion[
     Sin[x] Cos[y] + Sin[y] Cos[z] + Sin[z] Cos[x] < 0 && 
      x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < a^2,
     {{x, -a, a}, {y, -a, a}, {z, -a, a}}], 
    MaxCellMeasure -> .1/10]; // AbsoluteTiming
mesh
```

[image]

This took 370 seconds to compute. It is not a surface, like yours. Instead, half of the space is filled. The printed result was good. I also experimented with thickened surfaces but I was not able to get a good result (probably more because of the printer, and my inexperience, than because of Mathematica).

Comment: thank you so much for the answer. i do not know how to export the drwaing to STL dile and do a 3D printing. this is my main problem now

Comment: @SelamoBasile How did you search the documentation when trying to figure out how to export? Did you also search Google and what specific search phrase did you use?

Comment: Thank you sir for the above code. I want to ask if I want to modify the thickness of the gyroid so as to obtain a less thick gyroid with larger pore sizes.